# Blogroll- Just for home page or is it more in it?

Tags: seo, blogroll

I am thinking to add some sister websites to my blogroll. One thing that I am unable to decide is that why do people only add the homepage to the blogroll? As all the pages of a website have their worth so why do people just focus on the home url as the most influential page?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because that's [what a blogroll is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blogroll#B). It's a list of other blogs, not a list of articles or random pages. Why is the homepage chosen when people link to other sites (e.g. on a links page, via a site button/banner, or when a blog/site is mentioned in an article)? Because [that's what a homepage is designed for](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homepage). It's where webmasters expect most visitors, especially new visitors, to start browsing from. That's why homepages often list the latest articles/news and often an introduction. It's the frontdoor/welcome mat.

Comment: if your comment was entered as an answer it would be marked as "correct" i'm sure :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using just the home page, you could create a landing page that tailors the information that you give them. In example, if the site with the blogroll is about kittens and you are sending them to a site that is about kittens, puppies, and baby hippos, you might want to create a landing page that highlights the kitten aspects of your site.